# Exception:"The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format"

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, azure, azure-storage

Hello guys I have a problem .... I have already created a queue but I need to create another queue so I write this code:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =
CloudStorageAccount.parse (storageConnectionString);
CoudQueueClient queueClient1= storageAccount.createCloudQueueClient();
Cloud Queue queue1 =queueClient1.getQueueReference("my-queue");
queue1.createIfNotExist ();
```

The first queue I called "myqueue" while this new I called "my-queue" but when you run this code:

```
queue1.createIfNotExist();
```

The exception that is thrown is `The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format ....`Does anyone know tell me why?

Comment: Can you try logging with a tool like Fiddler and see what is being passed?  Is `my-queue` the actual name of the queue?  The naming syntax is very strict and specific: http://blog.summitcloud.com/2010/03/azure-queue-naming-syntax-limitations-validation/

Comment: I have two CloudQueue.The first called "myqueue" and the other called "my-queue". Yes I read that the name must be specific and must be conform to rules...Now nothing works well!

Comment: You still might try Fiddler to see if there's any clues, like this here: http://blog.codingoutloud.com/2010/10/18/an-http-header-thats-mandatory-for-this-request-is-not-specified-one-cause-for-azure-error-message/

Comment: What was it?  You might post an answer to your own question of what fixed it for other's reference.

Comment: The fault was "storage emulator" ... it's not loaded correctly and it throws Exception!

Comment: It would be very helpful if you elaborated on how to resolve the problem. I myself am experiencing this and am trying to find the solution